# Push notifications with Ionic and Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've used these instructions to setup Push notifications with Firebase on iOS. I'm pretty sure I've setup all the Apple certificates correctly and I can sent the notifications from FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) just fine, and the status is "sent", but they never arrive in my iPhone.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Here's my code. Any advice why this is not working or how to debug it will be highly appreciated!! Many thanks!

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';

constructor(platform: Platform, private push: Push, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      this.pushNotifications();
    });
  }
  pushNotifications() {
    this.push.hasPermission().then((res: any) => {
      if (res.isEnabled) { console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');}
      else { console.log('We do NOT have permission to send push notifications'); }
    }).catch((error) => { console.log("Push Notification needs Cordova: " + JSON.stringify(error));});

    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: 'My_ID'
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {}
    };

    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
      if(notification.additionalData.foreground) {
        let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'New Push notification',
          message: notification.message
        });
        youralert.present();
      }
    });

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', JSON.stringify(registration)));
    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the payload `priority` to `high`?

Comment: @AL. How do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: It was actually set by default in Firebase. So no, this doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: i have similar issue with native push plugin. then i migrate to ionic-native fcm plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/). and this fcm plugin working .

Answer (score 0):

You should add the FCM plugin find in the link: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

Then after find the below file in plugin :

```
“AppDelegate+FCM”
```

Where you can find the below method:
    customDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Please replace below :

```
[FIRApp configure];

    with this

 // [START configure_firebase]
    if(![FIRApp defaultApp]){
        [FIRApp configure];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to send your push notifications from online apns tester tools? 
(like. http://pushtry.com/). If you still have the same problem check your ios certificates, configurations and device checks again.